# Use Perl to insert a dollar sign

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I am trying to write a Perl one-liner in a Bash script to change math-mode delimiters in a LaTeX file from "\[" and "\]" to dollar signs.

That is, I want to change `\[a + b = c\]` to `$a + b = c$`.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to escape the dollar sign in Perl correctly.

The closest I've gotten is to use `perl -pi -e 's/\[/\$/gm' file.tex`.  However, this inserts `\$` into the file instead of a single dollar sign.

Comment: Did you try using `$` without backslash?

Comment: I did try using `$`.  Results in an error: `Final $ should be \$ or $name at -e line 1, within string`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't inserting `\$`; you are simply only replacing the `[`, not `\[`, with a dollar sign. Compare:

```
# Wrong
$ perl -p -e 's/\[/\$/gm' tmp.txt
\$a + b = c\]

# Right
$ perl -p -e 's/\\\[/\$/gm' tmp.txt
$a + b = c\]
```

To replace both,

```
$ perl -p -e 's/\\\[|\\\]/\$/gm' tmp.txt
$a + b = c$
```

---

For what it's worth, you can do this with the standard editor `ed`, rather than `perl`, though the escaping gets a little hairy (even switching to tripleee's simpler regular expression for matching either delimiter; it looks the same, but the double `\\` are there for `printf`, not `ed`, since I'm using `|` in the substitution operator.):

```
$ cat tmp.txt
\[a + b = c\]
$ printf 's|\\\[][]|$|g\nwq\n' | ed tmp.txt
14
12
$ cat tmp.txt
$a + b = c$
```

Answer (score 5):

No, the problem is that you are replacing a (backslash-escaped) literal `[` with a (backslash-escaped) literal dollar sign, but not matching or replacing the literal backslash at all.

Try this.

```sh
perl -pi -e 's/\\[][]/\$/g' file.tex
```

The `/m` flag didn't seem useful so I took it out.

The square brackets are a character class `[...]` containing the two literal characters `]` and `[`. They have to be in this order, to keep the expression unambiguous (though it also looks funny). And of course, `\\` is a (backslash-escaped) literal backslash.